# How to automatically align an image in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

I have dozens of images of this coin at various rotations (34, 120, 170 degrees).  What would be the easiest and best way in Python to automatically align the images so they are "aligned" as shown in the image below?

[image]

Comment: Are the rotations these particular angles or can they be anything ? How does a human solve this ?

Comment: I don't want to sound pessimist, but this task can be extremely difficult.

Comment: A single sample image is by far insufficient.

Comment: Remaps an image to log-polar space. And use FFT for find cyclic shift.

Comment: see https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.730.9105&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: @AlexAlex: this assumes that you have the original, unrotated image. So what use would it be ?

Comment: Yes, you must have the original, an unrotated image of the coin. Sample.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular coin, the only true clue for orientation is the motto IN GOD WE TRUST (the other letters can also be used, but you need a guaranty that they are placed symmetrically). The head needs to be recognized as a head and will not provide very accurate orientation information.

Unfortunately, even detection of the characters is problematic, and a standard OCR package would miserably fail.

If I had to solve this (though need more samples), I think I would focus on the content of an outer ring and detect concentration of features.

Comment: I have tons of images to train a model to teach it what the correct orientation is.  I'm hoping to find a tutorial that I can follow.

Comment: The link provided by Alex Alex is way past my level of understanding.  I'm hoping for an easier to follow tutorial.  Didn't realize it would be so tough.  Was hoping to create a model to tell it what it should look like and then it would rotate the image accordingly.

Comment: @user2607686: you didn't say that you wanted to use a specific technique (presumably deep learning - which IMO is a bad idea).

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the this question, but if you had template you could use my math heavy solution:

(1) **align the circle**: use [cross-correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) to orient the image to template and then adjust using x-y shift

(2) **align the angle**: use a [Radon transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_transform) of both the x-y aligned image and the template. The cross-correlation of the Radon transforms to get the proper rotation angle.

I've done this before with electron microscope images of membrane proteins.

Comment: Hi!  Thanks for the info.  Sounds promising but a little over my head.  The following link has 2 quarter example images:  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1n6WOWrG0gqVgCtfX79rtzJH64bcHM-G8?usp=sharing   Can you provide a script that will get me started?